# Using Google Apps gmail with Symfony nahomail plugin

Tags: email, symfony1, gmail, google-apps

My boss asks me to update a domain to adopt Google Apps, now everything has been done except the website is still not updated to use the Google Apps gmail server.

The website is running on Symfony <del>1.4.x but</del> 1.2.9 and it is not the latest 1.4.x version, and it does not have Swiftmailer included. It now sends email (e.g. user registration confirm email) using the nahomail plugin.

Now I would like to make it send email using the Google Apps gmail server.

The website is going to be abandoned after a few months, for simplicity, I am going to do an update directly on the production server and so I am trying to avoid as many trial-and-errors as possible.

I wonder if anyone is actually using this plugin and can share the nahomail settings for gmail server that has been working nicely.

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even the very first 1.4 release includes swift, see [this link](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/tags/RELEASE_1_4_0/lib/vendor).

I've been successfully using swift with gmail's smtp server, these are the probable settings, according to nahoMailPlugin's readme and my working factories.yml:

```
connection:
  type:               smtp
  params:
    server:           ssl://smtp.gmail.com
    port:             465
    encryption:       ssl
    authentication:   
      username:       username@yourhost.com
      password:       password
```

Comment: I read the readme before, but I know bad things always happen, that's why I asked for people who have actually used this plugin with gmail server to share the settings if possible. I have finally made it working, as I expected there's really something bad happened, I spent a few hours and it just didn't work, and finally, the answer is, for the server, it requires adding the ssl:// before the smtp.gmail.com to work. That was a nightmare.

Comment: Anyway, thanks so much for your reply. This is still a useful one.